# Construct POST Json in React If Form Is Populated

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm struggling with constructing data for a POST request through a React `Form`. The `type` changes based on whichever `Form.Control` is populated, and if any two out of three (or all three) are filled it adds an `And` at the top level and populates the `metadata` type.

There are three levels of `metadata` types: `TeamXToScoreOverYGoals`, `TeamXToFinishInTopYPosition` and `TeamXToGetOverYPoints`.

First, here's the component. At the moment `simulatorApi.runSim` is being sent an empty payload:

```
export default function App() {
  const [teamX, setTeamX] = useState("");
  const [goalX, setGoalX] = useState(0);
  const [posx, setPosX] = useState(0);
  const [ptx, setPtX] = useState(0);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    simulatorApi.runSim(
      []
    );
    alert("submitted");
  };

  return (
      <h1>POST Constructor</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Row>
        <Form.Group controlId="teamX" bssize="large">
            <Form.Label>Team B</Form.Label>
            <br />
            <StyledInput
              as="select"
              required
              value={teamX}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setTeamA(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="smaller-input"
            >
              <option value={"Liverpool"}>Liverpool</option>
            </StyledInput>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group controlId="goalsX" bssize="large">
            <Form.Label>Goal X</Form.Label>
            <StyledInput
              size="sm"
              required
              type="integer"
              value={goalX}
              onChange={(e) => setGoalX(e.target.value)}
              className="smaller-input"
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group controlId="positionX" bssize="large">
            <Form.Label>Position X</Form.Label>
            <StyledInput
              size="sm"
              required
              type="integer"
              className="smaller-input"
              value={posx}
              onChange={(e) => setPosX(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group controlId="pointsX" bssize="large">
            <Form.Label>Point X</Form.Label>
            <StyledInput
              size="sm"
              required
              type="integer"
              className="smaller-input"
              value={ptx}
              onChange={(e) => setPtX(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Button type="submit">Create</Button>
      </Form>
  );
}
```

So for instance if we just want to query how many times Liverpool scored over 65 goals, you'd fill in Goal X `Form` above and leave the other two empty creating this payload:

```
{
  "data": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "type": "TeamXToScoreOverYGoals",
                "team": {
                    "teamId": 10,
                    "name": "Liverpool"
                },
                "yGoals": 65
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If however, you wanted any two of the three (or all of them) then you'd fill the relevant forms, and the `metadata` object gets moved one level down into `submetadata`. A new "And" `type` is added at the top level.

This is how the payload would look like for Liverpool to finish in top 3, score over 65 goals and collect over 75 points:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "metadata": {
            "type": "And",
            "submetadata": [{
                    "type": "TeamXToScoreOverYGoals",
                    "team": {
                        "teamId": 10,
                        "name": "Liverpool"
                    },
                    "yGoals": 65
                },
                {
                    "type": "TeamXToFinishInTopYPosition",
                    "teamX": {
                        "teamId": 10,
                        "name": "Liverpool"
                    },
                    "yPosition": 3
                },
                {
                    "type": "TeamXToGetOverYPoints",
                    "team": {
                        "teamId": 10,
                        "name": "Liverpool"
                    },
                    "yPoints": 75
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm struggling to visualise how to put this together via the `Form`. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the JSON based on the values of the form.

According to your question, you have two conditions or two types of JSON you need to construct.

1. When teamX and goalX only filled.
2. When teamx, goalX and any other filled.

Let us make conditions and construct the JSON accordingly.
Your `handleSubmit` function become like this,

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  let jsonData = {};
  if (!teamX || !goalX) return;

  // When teamX and goalX only filled.
  if (teamX && goalX && !posx && !ptx) {
    jsonData = {
      "data": [{
        "metadata": {
          "type": "TeamXToScoreOverYGoals",
          "team": {
            "teamId": 10,
            "name": teamX
          },
          "yGoals": goalX
        }
      }]
    }
  }
  // When teamx, goalX and any other filled.
  else {
    jsonData = {
      "data": [{
        "metadata": {
          "type": "And",
          "submetadata": [{
              "type": "TeamXToScoreOverYGoals",
              "team": {
                "teamId": 10,
                "name": teamX
              },
              "yGoals": goalX
            },
            {
              "type": "TeamXToFinishInTopYPosition",
              "teamX": {
                "teamId": 10,
                "name": teamX
              },
              "yPosition": posx
            },
            {
              "type": "TeamXToGetOverYPoints",
              "team": {
                "teamId": 10,
                "name": teamX
              },
              "yPoints": ptx
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
// post jsonData
alert("submitted");
```